# Calling Instagram 'www.instagram.com/explore/tags/{tag}/?__a=1' returns Instagram Login Page

Tags: html, json, instagram, instagram-api

I have used the [https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"](https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/%22) + Tag + "/?__a=1 to fetch some posts information related to a specific tag. I do not know what is the problem exactly, but used to my code worked properly, and now as output I have Instagram login page. I would appreciate if anybody could help me in this regard.

```
def get_ig_page(url):
   contents = request.urlopen(url).read()
   return contents
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What's the problem, where's your code?

Comment: @Christian Thank you! I have updated my question, and inserted a part of the code which requests data from the URL. However, my code is long with some processing on the returned json from the request. My problem is exactly in this function which returned as output json of Instagram Login Page (although some days ago, It worked properly and gave me the json content of a specific tag). I do not have any idea what causes such problem.

Comment: Is authentication needed and working for you?

Comment: What kind of authentication you mean? I just made request by using the above code. Could you please explain more.

Comment: Hi Negar,

I'm also using the same URL and have seen it stop working within the last 24 to 48 hours. In the past this would return JSON but now it's redirecting to a login page. Unfortunately this means our code has stopped working too.

This answer won't help you fix your issue but perhaps there's some comfort in knowing you're not alone.

If you find a work around please let us know!

Comment: Hi @ConorClafferty, Thank you, actually now I feel better:D. However, I am trying to find other solutions to work with Instagram data.

Comment: @NegarMaghsoudi yep the ?__a=1 which returns a json seems to have stopped working recently. I used it to get a post's json but not able to anymore. I've been searching for a solution too!

Comment: Hi ! Any news or solutions found (other Graph API) ? Thx

Comment: Hey @neilaur , I had to use web crawling in order to extract instagram posts and comments. i

Comment: @NegarMaghsoudi I will try, thx !

Answer (score 0):

I could also reproduce the behavior, but an easy solution is not available.

I have read this: "... the new Instagram Graph API, integrated now inside Facebook Graph API, introduced a new so-called Hashtag Search API which replaced the former Instagram Tag Endpoint."

The API was deprecated a year ago and was apparently working until now. You might need to update to the new Facebook Graph API, but I am not sure.

The [new hashtag search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/hashtag-search?locale=en_US) seems to be what you need to use now.

You also might be able to use the [instagram basic display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api).

P.S. Happy to learn about something else if anyone finds an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The problem is if you hit the explore tags API too frequently, they put a kind of ban on your IP for some time which redirects you to the login page.

However, the good part is that it gets lifted automatically between 24-48 hrs as it did for me.
I hope it gives a sigh of relief :)

**PS: I hit this API more than 1k times in an hour to fetch 100k posts and it worked pretty fine.**